# path to home on OSX and Windows 10

Tags: netlogo

1. I would like the path to the user's home directory, on both OSX and Win 10.  How is this done in NetLogo?
2. How can a user configure the start up user directory for NetLogo? (I know this can be done via the OS. I am asking for a `.cfg` file of some sort.)

Comment: I don't think either of these questions has any answer besides what Charles said.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your first question, the `pathdir` extension has a reporter that returns the user's home directory.

`pathdir:get-home-path`
Returns a string with the full (absolute) path to the user's home directory, as specified by the "user.home" environment variable of the host operating system.

I believe this is usually set properly in Windows 10 and OSX.

Comment: I'm aware of `pathdir`, but I need a classroom solution that does not involve any extensions (or only bundled extensions).  Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is whether there is some option one can get to through the NetLogo.cfg file, but a quick look didn't turn up any documentation for it.